# Replacing Scene in cocos2dx from inside the current scene cause exception 0x77CAFF33

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am writing a simple cocos2d application in C++. The application changes the scene each time the user clicks on a button. This code is inside the init() function of a class MyLayerClass of type cocos2d::Layer

```
auto vbutton = static_cast< cocos2d::ui::Button*>(rootNode->getChildByName("MyButton"));
vbutton->addClickEventListener([=](Ref *) {
auto scene = MyLayerClass::createScene();
Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(scene);}
```

The application runs fine but when I quit the application, exception 0x77CAFF33 is thrown with a message "Access violation writing location 0x00000004". When I break it goes to >  ntdll.dll!_RtlEnterCriticalSection@4()  Unknown

Thanks for helping me

Comment: application runs fine than only execption comes when you quit your app then how you know problem is in replacing the scene or problem is in above code ?

Comment: check have you manually delete any pooled object.